# Monitor all requests and responses originating from XAMPP's apache server

Tags: apache-2.4, traffic, xampp

I am using Windows 10 and XAMPP to do local php development. I need to capture traffic originating from the apache server XAMPP uses but I can't figure out how. I'm using Fiddler and I can see my browser's requests to localhost but that's it.

Let's say I am loading a local php page, localhost/displaystuff.php, that uses curl to send off 10 different requests to 10 different hosts, then gets 10 different responses, sorts & displays those results. That's obviously coming from apache/XAMPP but none of it is visible to Fiddler (or I don't know how to make it visible), and to my knowledge there are no logs that display that information.

I need to see that traffic essentially like you would see it in the network tab of Chrome Devtools in the browser, each request with headers, body, timing information, etc along with the response provided to that request.

Can someone tell me where that information is logged (if it is), or give me a step by step method to capture / monitor it in realtime?

XAMPP 7.3.1 with Apache/2.4.37

Answer (score 0):

You can check the log in Xampp->apache->logs->access.log file . Open your accees.log file in any code editor or notepad then you see the realtime log.

Comment: This file does not include the header and the body of requests (at least in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler is for capturing local traffic, you need to look into fiddler everywhere.

With the proper apache modules enabled and some grepping you also do it on the apache server.(mod_dump_io)